# React Route: 404 Not Found after refreshing the deployed application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, routes

I'm working for a company and just deployed a project for them, but I encountered an issue. so, when you go to the link http://domain, you can go to the page, and from there you can go to any other page (react route), but if you go directly to http://domain/some-end-point, it shows 404 not found. does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That happened because your server side doesn't handle redirect to index.html, You can fix it by config your back end to always redirect to html, or simply you can fix it from react-router using **[HashRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter)** instead of **BrowserRouter**

[here is a full explanation about Server side vs client side routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8773272)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the public folder file name should be
**_redirects**

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

[refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4G3T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with .htaccess in the root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```